# how to fix NPE from fragment?

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, fragment

from fragment in my app i need to call public void that state in `myService.class`.

in fact i needed to do actions for buttons of mediaPlayer, that will be called from fragment.
when first time press `btn_PlayResume` - it `startService();`
when second time pressed - call pause();
and if again - just call play(), but not `startService()` again;

i have next code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (isPlaying){
            case 0:
                btn_PlayResume.setImageResource(R.drawable.select_btn_pause);
                isPlaying=1; //is playing
                getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
                break;
            case 1:
                btn_PlayResume.setImageResource(R.drawable.select_btn_play);
                isPlaying=2;// on pause
                myService.pauseAudio();
                break;
            case 2:
                btn_PlayResume.setImageResource(R.drawable.select_btn_pause);
                isPlaying=1; //is playing
                myServise.playAudio();
                break;
        }
    }
```

but when i run my app, there NPE in `myService.pauseAudio();`

so, how can i fix it?
will be glad any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LocalBroadcastManager` instead of calling `pauseAudio()` and `playAudio()` method from `Service` by creating object of class in which extending `Service`.

Using `LocalBroadcastManager` send Intent with different action's from Activity to pause and play `MediaPlayer` in Service.

See following tutorial to use  `LocalBroadcastManager` :

[Java Android Program to Demonstrate Local BroadCast Manager](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-local-broadcast-manager/)

Comment: good solution, thanks!

but i will be very thankful, if you explain me one moment in your example.
`sendBroadcast();
        startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.Activityone"));`
what is `"android.intent.action.Activityone"` ??
and in my case i doesnot needed to start new activity...

Comment: @AndriyAntonov: `android.intent.action.Activityone` custom action string. you also need to create two action string. like `android.intent.action.MEDIA_PLAY`,`android.intent.action.MEDIA_PAUSE`

Comment: sorry, it was mistake click